# Basic question, error: substr out of range

Tags: c++, substr

So I'm writing a program and part of it is to deal with an array of strings, and from each element in the string array, I am trying to take out every bi-gram within the string and place that in another array.  I am trying to do this by using the substr function and have tried to tweak it but I continue to get an OOR error.

the code reads:

"numwords" is the number of words in the string array and
"lowpunct" is the array of strings

```
for(i=0; i<numwords;i++)
{                
    for(x=0; x<=lowpunct[i].length()-2;x++)
    {
        if(lowpunct[i].length()-2 <=0)
        {
            bigram[count]=lowpunct[i];
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            bistring=lowpunct[i].substr(x,2);
            bigram[count]=bistring;
            count++;
            bistring="";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `<=` in the loop intentional?

Comment: Yes, I thought an issue might be that the string was too short and the "-2" wouldn't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string::length() is a size_t which is unsigned, so

```
if(lowpunct[i].length()-2 <=0)
```

will be a problem when a string with a length less than 2 is encountered.  This is because the result of underflowing an unsigned integer is that the 
number wraps around at the highest value. The for loop conditional is also wrong.

Rewrite them something like this:

```
 for(x=0; x+2 <= lowpunct[i].length();x++)
 if(lowpunct[i].length() <= 2)
```

Comment: How so? Would you suggest anything?

Comment: Well, you were correct :P but can you explain in simpler terms why it was the issue? I'm unfamiliar with "underflowing an unsigned integer"

Comment: @Sam, I meant basically attempting to make the unsigned value negative by subtracting more than its current value.  The rules for conversions can be tricky, but in this case, the comparison is made using unsigned values so it fails to work as you might expect.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you are going from 0 to lowpunct[i].length()-2. (including the size-2). That means that there is only 1 character left. Change the "<=" in the for loop to just be "<".